# How to log on Windows 7 as administrator

Tags: windows-7, login

On Windows 7 Home Premium, I have two users, 'admin' and 'user'. admin was been hidden by a wrong operation, so now only 'user' is shown on the logon screen.

Since 'user' cannot change any logon settings, I can do nothing actually. How can I logon as user 'admin' and change the logon settings?

Comment: How was the admin account hidden? Try running `net user administrator /active:yes` from an *elevated* Command Prompt.

Comment: Thx, disabled as [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/16378967-8a39-4aef-85e4-d859a71648d3). And the command returns **"Access is denied"**.

Comment: Is the reg value stores in some file as plain text? Can I change it via another system (i.e. Linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think you should do.

1. Try restarting your computer in safe mode to see if now, the administrator account now shows up. If so (or if you're directly brought to the desktop - I haven't used safe mode in a while), use it to restore your settings so it appears again.
2. Enable the built-in "almighty" administrator, which should have all the rights required to re-activate the normal administrator, then disable the almighty one again. Or you could keep using it, but that's not recommended security-wise.

Useful links:

Starting your computer in safe mode:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/Start-your-computer-in-safe-mode

Enabling the built-in elevated administrator in Windows 7:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/507-built-administrator-account-enable-disable.html

Comment: Thx, I tried the option 1, but the admin not appears. And seems that I cannot enable 'adminstrator' eithter since access is denied.

Comment: @fenghse: Did you try all methods mentioned to activate the elevated administrator? Including this one? ( http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/102552-built-administrator-enable-winre.html ) Did you run as administrator when it was asked to do so? Alternatively, perhaps you have a Windows restore point recent enough that would allow you to revert your computer to the state it was in before you made the mistake? Or is it a change too old for that? But seriously, with either of those methods, you should be able to get the elevated administrator to appear. Try them one after the other. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for double posting, but I just stumbled upon this. http://www.davidtosoff.com/2011/09/08/re-enable-a-disabled-administrator-user-in-windows-7/ If getting the elevated administrator doesn't work, this sounds like it would work. If it doesn't, well, 1. it's weird and 2. you're probably screwed and need to reinstall Windows. oo'

Comment: I try to run the 'cmd' as administrator, get prompt "To continue, type an adminstrator password, and then click yes", but NO dialog box to input user name or password, wiered.

Comment: Heh. Happy to know your problem has been solved (although it was more like getting around it. :p) By the way, if you had that prompt in the command window, you would never have gotten a pop-up. You needed to type the password directly into the black window and press Enter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7001/discussion-between-fenghse-and-ariane)

Answer (score -1):

On the Welcome screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> and a text field login prompt will be displayed.  You can type the username "Administrator" here.

Comment: Thx. I tried, but no text field appears.